# Boto3 DirectoryService: create_microsoft_ad fails

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, aws-directory-services

I am trying to create a Microsoft AD using the boto3 library in python. I am able to create it from the AWS console, but when i try to do it from my script using the same values i used when i tried from the console, it fails with the following error:

```
botocore.errorfactory.ClientException: An error occurred (ClientException) when calling the CreateMicrosoftAD operation: Invalid VPC ID. : RequestId: <id>
```

The exception response has a HTTP status code of 400.

I have the access key saved locally the way its mentioned [here](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/boto_config_tut.html) for windows and the user it belongs to has the permissions mentioned [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/UsingWithDS_IAM_ResourcePermissions.html) for CreateMicrosoftAD. (Since this is a test setup, I've given the user full access.)

The script is given below:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ds', region_name='us-west-2')
response = client.create_microsoft_ad(
    Name='test1.test2.com',
    ShortName='test1',
    Password='TestPassword1',
    Description='test description',
    VpcSettings={
        'VpcId': 'vpc-1234abcd',
        'SubnetIds': [
        'subnet-1235abcd',
        'subnet-1236abcd'
        ]
    }
)
```

I've added mock values for the VPC and subnet IDs here, but i verified in the console that i was using the IDs for available VPC and subnets. The create_microsoft_ad call is done as mentioned [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ds.html#DirectoryService.Client.create_microsoft_ad).

I am not sure if i am missing a step in the IAM user setup or in the script. Please let me know if i need to provide more information. Thanks!

Comment: It is possible in AWS console, you are using a region different from `us-west-2`. Or Boto3 is using the wrong credentials. See: http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html for configuring credentials. The one you used was for `Boto2`.

Comment: I tried hard-coding the credentials in the boto3.client call too and i am still getting the same error. But changing the region worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible in AWS console, you are using a region different from `us-west-2`

Or `Boto3` is using the wrong credentials. See: [Configuring Credentials](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html) for configuring credentials. The one you used was for Boto2.